# Changing date format coming from database?

Tags: php, mysql

So i am busy with coding a program though the date format is Y-m-d but i need it to be the european date format. thus having to be d-m-Y but i do not know how to do this since the files come directly from my database. `echo $row['Datum'];`if possible i'd love some help with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `date()` like:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Datum']));
```

Ex:

```
$row['Datum'] = '2017-06-30';
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Datum']));
// Output: 30-06-2017
```

[Php Fiddle Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d21c713d06e3a9069d06507289fbe1517040a2ec)

Comment: Thanks it helped alot ^^ it actually did exactly as it was supposed to so thanks for that mate ^^